# Search and replace an exact string, no matter if surounded or within another word

Tags: search, vim, replace, vi

I would like to find an exact string, which can be anywhere within a text or word.

```
.test_block
  .test_block--yellow
.another_test_block
  .block_test_block
```

should be

```
.test_div
  .test_div--yellow
.another_test_div
  .block_test_div
```

when running a `s/test_block/test_div/c`. The example on the left does not work. It does though with the `/g` flag enhanced. Anyone an idea, why this does not work with confirmation (`/c`)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that substitution should work. Perhaps it's a range issue? Try `:%s/test_block/test_div/g`.

Comment: @bgoldst okay I just realised it does work with `/g` but not with `/c`

Comment: somehow this feels like superuser rather than stackoverflow

Comment: @GeoffreyWiseman could be, but here are quite a few vim questions, so I guess it's alright.

Comment: I guess I ask IDE questions here too -- and although vim is more generalized than an IDE... never mind. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it correctly, just make sure you use a range where the command operates. For example:

```
:%s/test_block/test_div/g       " every line
:10,20s/test_block/test_div/g   " lines 10 to 20
```

If you want to do it globally and with the confirmation, include both flags:

```
:%s/test_block/test_div/gc
```

Comment: Updated the answer :-D

Comment: okay, you're right. But this seems arbitrary, how is `/c` alone behaving that it only seems to take the first word of a line?

Comment: @supersize this is the "normal" behavior. If you don't include any flags, it just operates on the first match of the line. If you include `g`, it operates on all matches of the line (not to be confused with `%` which is the line range). Including `c` is independent. It may ask for the first one only or all in each line, depending on the presence of `g`

Comment: @supersize Happy to help!